# Angular2 Spinner httpInterceptor with loading config in prebootstrap (app initizer)

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I am trying to migrate my existing code in 1.3 to 2. I have a configuration service that loads before application gets bootstrapped. Also I need to show a spinner which uses httpInterceptor. I am subscribing to SpinnerService Observable in App component. But as http call is before bootstraping, observable is always undefined.

```
  @NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule,SharedModule, AppRoutingModule
providers: [

    {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: (backend:XHRBackend, options:CustomOptions) => {
            return new HttpService(backend, options, new SpinnerService());
        },
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    },
    SpinnerService ,
    ConfigService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.loadConfig(),
        deps: [ConfigService],
        multi: true
    },
    {
        provide: RequestOptions,
        useClass: CustomOptions

    },
],
declarations: [AppComponent ],

bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

})

**Method in app.component.ts**

```
private createServiceSubscription() {
    this.subscription = this.spinnerService.spinnerObservable.subscribe(show => {
        if (show) {
            this.startSpinner();
        } else {
            this.stopSpinner();
        }
    });
}
```

**Spinner Service:**
export class SpinnerService {

```
public spinnerObserver: Observer<boolean>;
public spinnerObservable: Observable<boolean>;

constructor() {

    this.spinnerObservable = new Observable<boolean>((observer: Observer<boolean>)  => {
            this.spinnerObserver = observer;
        }
    ).share();
}

showSpinner() {
    if (this.spinnerObserver) {
        this.spinnerObserver.next(true);
    }
}

hideSpinner() {
    if (this.spinnerObserver) {
        this.spinnerObserver.next(false);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to show spinner using customHttpService right from prebootstrap

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BehaviorSubject.  BehaviorSubject emits an initial value, that subscribers will get immediately.

```
//private
this.spinnerObserver = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

//public
this.spinnerObservable = this.spinnerObserver.asObservable().share();
```

Comment: I changed to BehaviorSubject as above. Observer is defined however spinnerObserver.next(true) is not reaching to subscriber. However it reaches subscriber for false value. Not sure whats wrong. I am still debugging

Comment: Looks like it always taking initial value. Not the latest value